# Trigger jenkins pipeline automatically when changes made in the AWS CodeCommit repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, aws-codecommit

I am looking to trigger jenkins pipeline under multi-branch pipeline whenever there is any changes in the AWS CodeCommit repo.
For example, if there is any commit
pushed or any PR raised. Any idea how we could achieve this.

I know there is AWS CodeCommit trigger plugin which uses SNS/SQS (https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-codecommit-trigger/) to.trigger pipeline but the build trigger option is not appearing in the multi-branch pipeline configuration.

Comment: Did you try with the "related questions"?

Comment: I did but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: DId you try the same but with github, bitbucket or gitlab? Do you knwow what a webhook is? Are you using a declarative pipeline or scripted pipeline?

Comment: Looks like Jenkins supports automatic triggering of build for gitlab, bitbucket etc. but not for codecommit. So just wanted to know if there is any other way